# Should I use RTK Query per base URL or Resource?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am working in a big project with a lots of **base URL** and **resources** that we can undestand as a lot of diferent integrated services.

Pluging RTK on my application following the **resource line** (Isolated), that i have a createApi() per resource.

I'm following this path because each resource has all **CRUD** methods and some custom ones, imagining we would have 10 methods (calls) to manage each resource And, using a single create API, I could have 200 methods on a single createApi/reducerPath.

example: (What i imagine that's solve my problem)

```
// users-api.ts
 export const usersApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'usersApi',
    baseQuery: httpClientBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/' // (same base url)
    })
  // getUsers(), getUser(), getManyUsers() createUser(), updateUser(), ... 
 })

// cards-api.ts
 export const cardsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'cardsApi ',
    baseQuery: httpClientBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/' // (same base url)
    })
  // ...
 })

// accounts-api.ts
 export const accountsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'accountsApi ',
    baseQuery: httpClientBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/' // (same base url)
    })
  // ...
 })

// preferences-api.ts
 export const preferencesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'preferencesApi',
    baseQuery: httpClientBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/' // (same base url)
    })
  // ...
 })

// templates-api.ts
 export const templatesApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'templatesApi',
    baseQuery: httpClientBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/' // (different base url)
    })
  // ...
 })

...
```

From the RTK Documentation:

"createApi(): The core of RTK Query's functionality. It allows you to define a set of endpoints describe how to retrieve data from a series of endpoints, including configuration of how to fetch and transform that data. In most cases, you should use this once per app, with "one API slice per base URL" as a rule of thumb."

The question, is it okay to use RTK that way (per resource)? will I have performance problem, or would it not be the right way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We recommend that you should have one `createApi` per interconnected data source - usually that would be one per domain. If you split it up into multiple `createApi` calls, those apis could not influence each other, so a mutation at one endpoint could not automatically trigger a re-fetch of laterally affected data from another `createApi`.

Even if you have only one `createApi` call, you can still split it up over multiple files using the [Code splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting) approach using `injectEndpoints`.

```
// a central, potentially empty api definition
import { emptySplitApi } from './emptySplitApi'

const extendedApi = emptySplitApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    // adding only this endpoint in this file
    example: build.query({
      query: () => 'test',
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
})

// and exporting the hook to be used from components
export const { useExampleQuery } = extendedApi
```

Comment: "usually that would be one per domain" removed my doubt. Thanks for the answer and the tip.

Comment: By the way, we recently updated the docs - by now there should be about 10 new infoboxes making this more obvious :)

Comment: @phry I'm facing to same dilemma but my case is more about endpoints that needs or not authorization headers. Is there any good way to implement that?

for ex: I have 2 endpoints `/account/info` and `/account/<id>`, the 1st one needs auth  but the other doesn't.

As of docs, such of headers could be set with `prepareHeaders` but it's in the scope of baseQuery not in the endpoint. So far, the workaround I found is to use `queryFn` instead where I can fetch the token I want to use but it becomes very redondant when I have several endpoints that needs the same set of headers.

any insights?

Comment: You can either filter in `prepareHeaders` for endpoint names (see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989313/disable-rtk-query-prepareheaders-on-specific-endpoint ) or just return a `headers` property from each `query` function, just as you would when calling `fetch` by hand.